# Session start on Laravel

Tags: php

Please help, I get this `Exception` on:

```
session_start();
```

> open(/home/en/incentivestogirls/app/storage/sessions/sess_uj043d3ka2vgv3iumu6vf1cbr1, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file system (30)

Answer (score 0):

Storage directory needs to be writable by web server. So make your `app/storage` folder writeable by it for example with command

```
chmod 777 -R app/storage
```

Which is not good but works, because you allow to every user RWX access to this folder. A better solution is to use `755`.

If permission change does not help, there can be a serious problem with your HDD (failing, run out of memory,...). Try to contact an administrator or provider.